# How do I access authorization token in my Api?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, api

Is there a way I can access this parameter/bearer token in my Api?
[image]

This is the method in the API were I need to access it:

```
[HttpGet]
    [Route("user/{token}")]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Item>> GetUserItems(//TOKEN token)
    {
        var itemsQuery = Context.Items.Where(i => i.User.JwtToken == token);

        return await itemsQuery.ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the bearer token is in a header field, you could try it with the [FromHeader] attribute

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("user")]
public async Task<IEnumerable<Item>> GetUserItems([FromHeader(Name = "Authorization")] string token)
{
    token = token.Replace("Bearer ", "");
    var itemsQuery = Context.Items.Where(i => i.User.JwtToken == token);

    return await itemsQuery.ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 Context.Request.Headers.Authorization.Parameter
```

will give you the bearer token.